# Read response from "tell" command

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I need to read response (on Domino Console) for command like: "tell http show security"

It works when I do 'show' commands (see example below). Res will get full response.

```
res = notesSession.SendConsoleCommand("server", "show server")
```

However that does not work for 'tell' commands. It returns a string

```
res = notesSession.SendConsoleCommand("server", "tell http show security")
```

> Command has been executed on remote server. Use 'Live' console option,
> in future, to view response from server.

I have also tried to do

```
tell http show security >http_security.txt
```

File gets same string

> Command has been executed on remote server. Use 'Live' console option,
> in future, to view response from server.

Is there a nice way to read response?

p.s. I would like to avoid scanning log.nsf as it's going to be heavy task.

Thanks.

Comment: Tell commands instruct the console to send a message to another task. I don't think the console can sit there and wait for output from the other task in order to send it back to you. Amongst other problems, it would have no way of knowing when the other task is generating output from the tell or just writing some random log message.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz I agree and thought the same. Unfortunately it seems the only way to solve that is to parse log.nsf which is really bad idea. Thanks.